# Trying to find a NICE form of : $\sum_{m=1}^{n}\lfloor\log_2m\rfloor$ [ Mathematical Gazette 2002 ]

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> $Q.$ Find a NICE form of : $$\sum_{m=1}^{p}\lfloor\log_2m\rfloor$$

**APPROACH :** We have , $$\lfloor\log_21\rfloor⠀\color{red}{\lfloor\log_22\rfloor}⠀\lfloor\log_23\rfloor⠀\color{red}{\lfloor\log_24\rfloor}⠀\lfloor\log_25\rfloor⠀\lfloor\log_26\rfloor⠀\lfloor\log_27\rfloor⠀\color{red}{\lfloor\log_28\rfloor}⠀........⠀\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor$$ $$0⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\color{red}1⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀1⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\color{red}2⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀2⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀2⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀2⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\color{red}3⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀$$

We know that : $$\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor=k$$

**STEP 1 :** Sum of terms b/w $\lfloor\log_22^{k-1}\rfloor\to\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor$ . Number of terms b/w $2^{k-1}\to2^k$ is $2^{k-1}$ .

Hence the  sum upto $\underline{\lfloor\log_22^{k-1}\rfloor\to\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor}$ will be : $$S_{2^{k-1}\to2^k}=\lfloor\log_22^{k-1}\rfloor2^{k-1}+\lfloor\log_22^{k}\rfloor$$ $$S_{2^{k-1}\to2^k}=(k-1)2^{k-1}+k$$

Now sum upto $\underline{\lfloor\log_21\rfloor\to\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor}$ : $$S_{ \lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor}=k+\underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^{k}(k-1)2^{k-1}}_\phi$$

$\Rightarrow$ Now we'll solve for $\phi$ , $$\phi=0.2^0+1.2^1+2.2^2+3.2^3+.......+(k-1)2^{k-1}$$ $$\phi=2+2.2^2+3.2^3+.......+(k-1)2^{k-1}⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀(1)$$ $$\frac{\phi}{2}=1+2.2+3.2^2+.......+(k-1)2^{k-2}⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀(2)$$

Substracting $eq^n(1)$ from $eq^n(2)$ $$-\frac{\phi}{2}=\underbrace{1+2+2^2+2^3+.......+2^{k-2}}_{n-1⠀terms⠀(GP)}-(k-1)2^{k-1}$$ $$-\frac{\phi}{2}=(2^{k-1}-1)-(k-1)2^{k-1}$$ $$\phi=2((k-1)2^{k-1}-2^{k-1}+1)$$ $$\phi=2^k(k-2)+2$$

$\Rightarrow$ Using the value of $\phi$ in $S_{ \lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor}$ : $$S_{ \lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor}=k+2^k(k-2)+2$$

**STEP 2 :** Let there be a term $\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor$ b/w $\lfloor\log_22^{k-1}\rfloor\to\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor$ : $$S_{\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor}=S_{ \lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor}-\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor-\delta$$

Here $\delta$ is the sum of terms b/w $\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor$  and $\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor$ . Number of terms b/w $\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor$  and $\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor$ is $(2^k-p)-1$

Hence $\delta$ : $$\delta=(2^k-p-1)\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor$$

Now , $$S_{\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor}=k+2^k(k-2)+2-\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor-(2^k-p-1)\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor$$

Here are some important conditions : $$ \lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor=k$$ $$\lfloor\log_22^{k-1}\rfloor=\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor$$ $$\lfloor\log_22^k\rfloor=\lfloor\log_22^{k-1}\rfloor+1=\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor+1$$

**FINALLY :** after further simplifying , I got  :

> $$\sum_{m=1}^{p}\lfloor\log_2m\rfloor=\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor(p+1)-2^{\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor+1}+2$$

**DOUBT :** Is there a simpler OR better approach than this ?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta. He wants a better approach.

Comment: I suspect that you will really enjoy this video: https://youtu.be/uJeLadKSFFM (note: the final answer is written incorrectly, but it's corrected in the comments).

Comment: Congratulations ! You found Diego Torres 's formula (have a look at sequence $A061168$ in $OEIS$)

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes you're correct , I found it there ... but I shared my approach to the problem , which is different , I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the same calculation as yours, but much more compact; you might find the technique in the first two lines valuable.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{p}\lfloor\log_2m\rfloor &= \sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{1\le k\le (\log_2m)} 1 \\
&= \sum_{1\le k\le (\log_2 p)} \sum_{m=2^k}^{p} 1 \\
&= \sum_{1\le k\le (\log_2 p)} (p+1-2^k) \\
&= \lfloor\log_2p\rfloor (p+1) - \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor}2^k = \lfloor\log_2p\rfloor (p+1) - \big( 2^{\lfloor\log_2p\rfloor+1}-2 \big).
\end{align*}

Comment: Your final expression has a typo: the sum of the finite geometric series is $2^{\lfloor \log_2 p \rfloor + 1} - 2$.